# Partial Fraction Decomposition of a Complex Rational Function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n$ be distinct complex numbers. Show that a rational function of the form

$$ f(z) = \frac{b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_{n-2}z^{n-2}+b_{n-1}z^{n-1}}{(z-r_1)(z-r_2) \cdots (z-r_n)}$$

can be written as a sum

$$f(z) = \frac{A_1}{z-r_1} + \frac{A_2}{z-r_2} + \dots +  \frac{A_n}{z-r_n}$$

for some constant $A_1,\dots A_n$.

Solution:

Defining

$g(z) = f(z) - \frac{A_1}{z-r_1} + \frac{A_2}{z-r_2} + \dots +  \frac{A_n}{z-r_n}$ where $A_1,\dots A_n$ are the residues of $f$ at each of the points $r_1,\dots r_n$.

I suppose I want to show that $g(z)$ is 0, but not sure how to do this. I know that $g(z)$ tends to 0 as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$....

Comment: The algebraic solution is if $h(a) \ne 0$ then $\frac{g(z)}{h(z) (z-a)}= \frac{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}}{z-a}+\frac{g(z)-\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}h(z)}{h(z) (z-a)} = \frac{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}}{z-a}+\frac{f(z)}{h(z)}$. The complex analysis  solution is if $deg(g) < n$ and $G(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (z-a_k)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{c_k}{z-a_k}$ is entire then $G$ is a polynomial (since it is rational and entire) and $\lim_{|z|\to \infty} G(z) = 0$ means $G  = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $r_j$ is a pole of order $ \le 1$ of $f$, hence there is a polynomial $p_j$ such that

$f(z)= \frac{A_j}{z-r_j}+p_j(z)$

(Laurent expansion around $r_j$).

Then it follows that $g$ is a polynomial. Since $g(z) \to 0$ for $|z| \to \infty$, we get $g(z)=0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Can you clarify here? I get that $f(z)$ has the form you described. It doesn't immediately follow to me why $g(z)$ is a polynomial, since when I define $g(z)$ I am subtracting all of the $\frac{A_k}{z-r_k}$ simultaneously.